# Case Sensitive Search and Replace with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a little script to replace characters in a text with AppleScript.

Unfortunately upper and lower case is not being recognized by AppleScript.

Any idea how to take upper and lower case into account?

```
set input to "ApeAlexaBobBorder"
set the clipboard to replaceText(input as string)

on replaceText(textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "A"
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", A"
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs

    return textString
    
end replaceText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the comparison(s) in a `considering` statement, for example:

```
considering case
   set the clipboard to replaceText(input as string)
end considering
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-130224) for more information.

Comment: Actually `considering case` affects only *text comparisons* (is something equal to something else) but not `text item delimiters` related stuff.

Comment: @vadian : `text item delimiters` respect the 'considering' and `ignoring` attributes in current AppleScript versions

Comment: @vadian, from the link in his answer: **Special Considerations** Because `text item delimiters` (described in version) respect `considering` and `ignoring` attributes in AppleScript 2.0, delimiters are case-insensitive by default. Formerly, they were always case-sensitive. To enforce the previous behavior, add an explicit considering case statement.

Comment: @vadian Perfect. Thanks. Works fine now.